# Random padding at top of the page on mobile version

Tags: html

[image] - this is what I'm getting on my mobile version, everything is fine for the desktop media query, not sure exactly why this is happening. I've tried looking for any elements that could be padding the .header down but haven't really found anything.

**Website for reference:** https://muchkler.github.io/Serenity/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="apple-icon.png" />
    <title> Explore Our Home </title>
</head>

<body>



<div class="header">
<div class="navbar">    
<nav> 
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Destinations</li>
        <li>Earth</li>
        <li>Memorial</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h2> Explore our beautiful<br>Earth.</h2>
    <p>Too focused on our phones, we often forget how beautiful Earth is. <br>Not everyone is equipped with the financials to travel. Explore Earth right here.</p>
    <h3> Explore now.</h3>
    <div class="explore"><a href="#firstpage"><img src="images/arrow.png" width="30px"></a></div>
</div>    
</div>   


<div class="firstpage" id="firstpage">
    <div class="firstelements">
        <h4>Yosemite</h4>
        <p class="yosemite">Not just a great valley, but a shrine to human foresight, the strength of granite, the power of glaciers, the persistence of life, and the tranquility of the High Sierra. First protected in 1864, Yosemite National Park is best known for its waterfalls, but within its nearly 1,200 square miles, you can find deep valleys, grand meadows, ancient giant sequoias, a vast wilderness area, and much more.</p>
        <div class="yosemitebtn"><a href="https://www.nps.gov/yose/index.htm">Learn more</a></div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* First page styling */

body{
    margin: 0;
}
.header{
    background: url(images/matt-sclarandis-159838-unsplash.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height: 100vh; 
    vertical-align: baseline; 
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

h1{
    color: white; 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar li{
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 10px;
    color: white; 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
}

.navbar ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px; 

}

.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    color: white; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 100px;
}

h2{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

h3{
    padding-top: 200px;
    line-height: 0px;
    font-weight: 100; 
    font-size: 15px;; 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.explore{
    opacity: 0.65;
}

.explore:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
}

/* First page styling */

/* Second page styling */

.firstpage{
    background: url(images/aniket-deole-294646-unsplash1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height: 100vh; 
    vertical-align: baseline; 
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;

    }

.firstelements{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 250px;
    text-align: center; 
}

h4{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: white; 
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.yosemite{
    color: white; 
    padding-bottom: 15px ;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white; 
}

.yosemitebtn{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #2dcb70;
    width: 100px;
    height: 24px;
    border-color: #2dcb70;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto; 

}

/* Second page styling */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px){

    h2{
        font-size: 50px;
        padding-top: 100px;

    }

    p{
        max-width: 350px;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }

    h3{
        padding-top: 300px;
    }

    .navbar{
        float: right;
        padding-right: 250px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    h1{
        float: left; 
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin on the nav's ul is what's causing it.

```
/* Simple fix. */
.navbar ul { margin: 0; }
```

Or

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!